# Adding unit tests give 'The following id must have a positive value: testRunId.' in TFS 2012/2013

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

When I check in some c# unit tests to the company TFS 2013 server we started getting the following error on each build of our application

```
TF900548: An error occurred publishing the Visual Studio test results. Details: 'The following id must have a positive value: testRunId.'
```

All I can find on this when searching the web is this [blog](http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/rfennell/post/2013/03/23/TF900548-when-using-my-Typemock-2012-TFS-custom-build-activity.aspx) which does not tell me much.

It seems the tests are run but that the results can't be published because of this error. The summary says our solution was compiled and continues with

```
No Test Results
No Code Coverage Results
```

What am I missing?

**Update 1**

We just updated our source control and build servers to TFS 2013 and are still getting the error. I also created a new build definition based on TfvcTemplate.12.xaml but still get the same error.

**Update 2**

I get seven warnings in the TFS build summary. Six of those read

```
ALINK: Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor
```

and one reads

```
The project file "Setup\Setup.vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built.
```

The last one is because of an old setup project that is not longer supported in newer visual studio version but is still present in the solution.

Could any of these warnings be causing the problem?

**Update 3**

This problem has been gone for a while now. Nothing that I know of was changed... I suspect there was some connection issues with a database, but I don't know how this all is setup.

I does seem, however, that the problem was not related to any build warnings.

Comment: Did you try changing the target platform settings in the build definition? That might help to eliminate the `targets a different processor` warning. You could also set the logging verbosity for a build to `diagnostic` and see if there are any other hints contained in the log that help to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that tomorrow. :)